# how to create a blocking dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there any way to create blocking dialog box using Javascript/JQuery/Ajax ...

I have used the JQuery UI dialog box. As this is an asynchronous function, I used callback functions. However it makes a simple JS code of if/else very complex.

e.g.

```
ans1 = confirmBox("something"); 
 if(ans1){
    ans2 = dialogBox(); 
    if(ans2)
        alertBox();
    else {
        ans3 = dialogBox(); 
        ....
    }   
 }  
 else {
 }
```

... rest of the code

Callbacks make this very complicated. Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: You _could_ use the ugly browser prompts. Or write a helper function you can call that will conditionally run the asynchronous prompts you need based on state and feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make JavaScript block and wait for a condition. You need to use the callback method.

Maybe if you are needing all of these steps, it would be better to do it in a different manner.